# Dynamic type for UIButton's attributeTitle

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

Anyone ever got dynamic type working for `attributedTitle` on `UIButton`? Consider the super simple code below:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)!
let scaledFont = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: font)

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.titleLabel?.font = scaledFont
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true

let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [ .font: scaledFont ]
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Press me", attributes: attributes)
button.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)
```

If I scale the font size up and down using Accessibility Inspector, the button's size and label text doesn’t scale properly.

If I just call `button.setTitle()` passing an ordinary string, though, dynamic type scaling works fine.

Using the same pattern for attributed text directly on a `UILabel` works fine… it just seems to be when I use attributed text for a `UIButton`’s title.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome. Thanks

**Edit:** After a bit more poking, it looks like what is happening is that the text is trying to scale, but the button's width/height aren't growing with it. If I dial up dynamic type to the largest text size and then create the screen and proceed to shrink the font size, it works OK because the buttons width/height constraints are set to an initially large value. But if I start with a small dynamic type setting and grow larger, the button doesn't accommodate the text size change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I scale the font size up and down using Accessibility Inspector, the button's size and label text doesn’t scale properly.

To scale the attributed string label of a `UIButton` with the `Dynamic Type`, **set the title label as an attributed string first** and then put this element in the `setAttributedTitle` button method.

About the button size, specify the `sizeToFit` method of the button in the **traitCollectionDidChange** instance method of the [`UITraitEnvironment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment) protocol *(using constraints can be another solution as well)*.

I created a blank project in Xcode as follows:
[image]

Copy-paste the code snippet hereunder *(Swift 5.0, iOS 12)*:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    
        myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10,
                                                  left: 20,
                                                  bottom: 10,
                                                  right: 20)
        
        let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 19)!
        let scaledFont = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: font)

        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: scaledFont]
        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Press me",
                                                attributes: attributes)
        
        myButton.titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
        myButton.setAttributedTitle(myButton.titleLabel?.attributedText,
                                    for: .normal)

        myButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }


    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    
        myButton.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

... and you get the result hereafter:
[image]
If you need further explanation, I suggest to take a look at this [Dynamic Type kind of tutorial](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#text-size) that contains {code snippets + illustrations} and at this [WWDC detailed summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html) that deals with building apps with Dynamic Type.

⚠️ **EDIT 2021/02/15** ⚠️

Thanks to @Anthony's comment, I have improved this old solution to the new context as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 4.0

        let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)!
        let scaledFont = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: font)

        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: scaledFont]
        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Press Me Huge Button",
                                                attributes: attributes)

        myButton.titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
        myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        myButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        
        myButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedText,
                                    for: .normal)

        myButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        
        createConstraints()
    }
```

... and added constraints between the button and its content:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.myButton.setNeedsUpdateConstraints() // For updating constraints.
    }
}

private func createConstraints() {
    
    myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myButton.titleLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let spacing = 10.0
    myButton.titleLabel?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.trailingAnchor,
                                                   constant: -CGFloat(spacing)).isActive = true
    myButton.titleLabel?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.leadingAnchor,
                                                  constant: CGFloat(spacing)).isActive = true
    myButton.titleLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.topAnchor,
                                              constant: CGFloat(spacing)).isActive = true
    myButton.titleLabel?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myButton.bottomAnchor,
                                                 constant: -CGFloat(spacing)).isActive = true
}
```

With some new constraints for the button inside `Interface Builder`, I finally get those screenshots using the `Xcode` [Environment Overrides pane](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2019/#dynamic-type):
[image]
[image]

⚠️ **EDIT 2022/01/28** ⚠️

iOS 15 introduced a [new button style](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2021/2110059/#api-enhancements) that provides a native adaptation to the multiline titles and the [Dynamic Type](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2021/2110196/#button-styles) features.

No code is necessary anymore to reach the initial goal of Craig.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is following along, the key to resolving this is contained in the first para of @XLE_22's post but is quite subtle.

When calling `setAttributedTitle()` on the button, you need to pass the attributed string from the **label**. ie.  `myButton.titleLabel?.attributedText`... passing the local variable `attributedText` does not work.  I can't rationalise why this is the case though. Consider the following code:

```
myButton.titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
let labelAttributedText = myButton.titleLabel?.attributedText

myButton.setAttributedTitle(labelAttributedText, for: .normal)  // works
myButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)       // doesn't work
```

If I compare `attributedText` with `labelAttributedText`, I can see that the former is a `NSConcreteAttributedString` whereas the latter is a `NSConcreteMutableAttributedString`. Asking them if they are equal return `true` and a quick comparison of their attributes seems to suggest that they are indeed the same, but there must be something ever so slightly different.

I tried initially creating `attributedText` as a mutable attributed string, but that didn't help either.  Very puzzling, but a huge thanks to @XLE_22 for the tip... I doubt I would have ever tried that specific trick on my own.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5.5 & XCode 13

If you are using a custom font. Maybe this code will help you.

```
class DynamicSizeButton: UIButton {
func customStyle() {
    guard let currentFont = self.titleLabel?.font, let customFont = UIFont(name: currentFont.fontName, size: currentFont.pointSize) else {return}
    self.titleLabel?.font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledFont(for: customFont)
    self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    customStyle()
   }
}
```

USE.....

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the Dynamic Type feature is now automatically taken into account for the buttons in iOS 15 ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2021/2110196/#button-styles  